# How do I get my plotly.js chart to translate dates to the local region's language?

Tags: javascript, plotly, localization, translation, plotly.js

We are developing an AngularJS application using Plotly.js charts. The x axis on one of our charts displays dates:

[image]

These dates are passed to the chart in this format: `2022-11-01T06:01:00.000Z`.

One rule we have for our application is that all text needs to be translatable to other languages. So I'm wondering if Plotly.js has a property on the chart layout or data that tells it what language to translate dates to. Or to detect the region and translate the dates accordingly.

For example, here in North America, a date might be displayed as 'Jan 2023'. But if I were in Russia, I would like to see 'январь 2023' (or whatever the shorthand is, if they use shorthand).

Note that I'm not asking for regional formatting. I could format the date with `new Date(date).toLocaleDateString('ru-RU')` to get `01.11.2023`, but that's not what I'm asking. I'm asking for the translation of month names and week day names.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Plotly.js localization defaults to US English (en-US) and includes British English (en) in the standard bundle.

In order to use non-default locales, you need to load it/them first. You can use Plotly CDN url of the form `https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-locale-<YOUR-LOCALE>-latest.js`, eg. in your html add *after* the plotly.js script tag :

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-locale-ru-latest.js"></script>
```

Then, you can either set the locale to be used as the default for all Plotly plots :

```js
Plotly.setPlotConfig({locale: 'ru'});
```

... or set it for a specific plot via its `config` :

```js
const config = {locale: 'ru'};
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout, config);
```

For more information and a list of available locales, see [How to include localization](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/tree/master/dist#to-include-localization).